# pytest AssertionError raised when matching stdout using regex

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to match the stdout against a regex, by wrapping into a test case in pytest.
The following is my code:

```
import re, sys

class capture_print:
    def __enter__(self):
        self._original_stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout.flush()
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sys.stdout = self._original_stdout


def regex_test():
    out = '''[Task 0x7f6063018a90] Video stream download complete
        [Task 0x7f6063018be0] Audio stream download complete
        [Task 0x7f6062229d40] Merging streams complete
        '''
    l = re.compile(r'(\[Task \w+\] (?:Video|Audio|Merging) streams?(?: download | )complete\n)')
    print(''.join(l.findall(out)))


def temp():
    k, l, m = None, None, None
    print(f"[Task {hex(id(k))}] Downloading Video stream.....", end='\r')
    print(f"[Task {hex(id(k))}] Video stream download complete")
    print(f"[Task {hex(id(l))}] Downloading Audio stream.....", end='\r')
    print(f"[Task {hex(id(l))}] Audio stream download complete")
    print(f"[Task {hex(id(m))}] Merging streams.....",end='\r')
    print(f"[Task {hex(id(m))}] Merging streams complete\n")
    
    
        
def test_pipeline(capsys):
    with capture_print():
        temp()
        captured = capsys.readouterr()
        #print(captured.out)
        stdout_pattern = re.compile(r'(\[Task \w+\] (?:Video|Audio|Merging) streams?(?: download | )complete\n)')
        assert ''.join(stdout_pattern.findall(captured.out)) == captured.out[:-1]
```

The `capture_print` class acts as context manager to only capture the stdout of the `temp` function.

The following is the output of `temp()`

```
[Task 0x90ea10] Video stream download complete
[Task 0x90ea10] Audio stream download complete
[Task 0x90ea10] Merging streams complete
```

I have defined a test function `test_pipeline` to match the above output against a regex `out_pattern`.

But it results in an [AssertionError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeJq1.png)

The `regex_test` shows that the regex mentioned above successfully matches the output of `temp()`. So, there is nothing wrong with the regex.
Based on the error, `\r` seems not to be working.

I did try `print(captured.out)` to check the [stdout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCZlV.png) being captured, but it was the same as output of function `temp`.
Now, I am really confused as to why the AssertionError was raised.

Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem?

EDIT :

I think the problem is not clearly understood. I want the stdout to be equal to the following:

```
[Task 0x90ea10] Video stream download complete
[Task 0x90ea10] Audio stream download complete
[Task 0x90ea10] Merging streams complete
```

The hexadecimal number following `Task` is a memory address. It changes every time I execute the code. So, I plan on using regex for this. If I wanted this to be an actual test case, I would have to use Assertion instead of an if statement.

My strategy:

Define a regex that exactly only matches the stdout so that the string matched by the regex and the actual stdout are exactly the same and hence can be compared.

EDIT 2:

Solution:

When capturing stdout, each print statement's output acts as a string. So, the '\r' carriage return is just a character which is a part of a string. Only when the stdout is printed to terminal, the '\r' functionality takes effect.

Comment: I think, there should be some expected vs. actual comparison in the outputs of pytest. Have you had a look at that? I most likely would suspect some missing or additional newline character at the end for example or maybe some spaces.

Comment: @Christian Expected result will be that the regex matches the output and assertion is true. As of the actual results, I have included images. Initially, I also did suspect that it had to do with the spacing but re-checked and it had nothing to do with that. The problem is that pytest is not capturing carriage return resulting in 6 statements in the stdout instead of 3.  The second image shows the captured output.

Answer (score 0):

Your assert makes no sense.
You compare the raw output of `temp()` (as given by `captured.out[:-1]`) with your filtered version of exactly this output, that you create with `''.join(stdout_pattern.findall(captured.out))`.
This filtered version will only leave those lines, that fit your matcher and thus will never be the same as the whole output.

Edit: What you btw. wrote there as the output of `temp()` is not actually not its output, but the filtered one. That's where the confusion might origin from.

Edit2: Okay, after your comment I get your problem. The issue is, that you nowhere define, that you actually want to change the stdout. In your `capture_print` you have already everything prepared, so you can do it like this:

```
class capture_print:
    def __enter__(self):
        self._original_stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = self
        self.stdout_pattern = re.compile(r'(\[Task \w+\] (?:Video|Audio|Merging) streams?(?: download | )complete)')

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        sys.stdout = self._original_stdout
        sys.stdout.flush()

    def write(self, string):
        if self.stdout_pattern.match(string):
            self._original_stdout.write(string + "\n")
```

I basically replace the `sys.stdout` with the `capture_print` instance itself, so its `write` method will be called. There I match the given string (the one, that normally would be given to the stdout) with the pattern and only if they match, I write it to the `_original_stdout`, which is the `sys.stdout`.
Note, that I had to remove the `\n` there from the regex, as the line-ending symbol was always sent separately.

Comment: Sorry, but I am unable to understand your edit. The output of temp() is not filtered in any manner. If by filtered you mean captured.out[0:-1]; I am just removing the last character as it is a trailing newline. I checked and it is not important. It is not the reason for this error. Please look at the images once again. Why was carriage return not read as it should be, because then only 3 sentences of stdout would be there instead of 6 sentences. And read my EDIT for more clarity.

Comment: @SaiChaithanya Okay, now I get it. Please see my second edit. I think that fits your needs better. Let me know, if there still is something wrong with that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Though your answer doesn't exactly solve my problem, it helped to get to know the problem better and helped me solve it. Basically, the carriage return character '\r' is also captured as a normal character as a part of the string. Only when the stdout is printed to the terminal, its functionality is applied.